# How to post data with json to web service in swift

Tags: json, swift, web-services, http-post, http-get

I have to send username and password from ios app to web services (created asp.net) to enter the application.

if the user information is `username:john & password: 123456` , the web services return something that is like "1" means the user is registered before so user can enter the app. Or return "0" means the user is not registered before, can't enter the app.

So, How can i do that ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i do this please help me ? i am new.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
func login()
{
    let parameters = ["username": "john","password":"123456"]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://myurl.com",parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON).responseJSON
        {
            response in switch response.2
            {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                print(JSON)
                let response = JSON as! NSArray
                print(response)
                break
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                break
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use alamofire as a begining. Firstly i want to learn in normal ways then i use alamofire. Thanks your helping.